# Make a copy of a Joomla site to a new folder on the same database?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla1.5

I need to make a copy of my Joomla site into a new directory on the same domain Because I need to migrate from version 1.5.9 to 2.5.25. (there's no upgrade from 1.5.9 to 1.7)

But when I copy into just another folder, do I then need to change the prefix of the database and tables in the database after copying? And how do I do so? Will there be any conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

If you are cloning the website to another folder you will need to make a copy of the database and edit the configuration.php to point to the new DB otherwise you will have two sites using the same database - which is not good. 
I'm puzzled as to why you would do this though, would it not be better to create a Joomla 2.5.3 website in a subfolder and then us SP Upgrade to port the data? Or maybe install JUpgrade into your 1.5 Joomla and have it create the 2.5.3 in a subfolder for you. 
Either way you should update to 1.5.25 before doing anything (you can do this automatically using the free Akeeba AdminTools extension). https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/46-software/855-admintools.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://docs.joomla.org/Moving_the_site_among_directories/sub-directories

However I agree with the comment above: It's not a good idea.